# Consider a String a f-string in Python

Tags: python, f-string

Suppose I have

```
x = 3 
s = "f'12{x}4'"
```

How to consider s as f-string to print `1234`, like writing `print(f'12{x}4')`
when I print `s`, it prints it as it as: `f'12{x}4'`

Comment: maybe `print(eval(s))`

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. An f string uses the format `s=f'12{3}4'`. It is not wrapped in quotation marks. Consider reading a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) about them.

Comment: F-strings are a feature of the Python language. They work because interpreter (or compiler, or other runtime) understand the python source and know how to interpret that syntax. You can treat this string as python source code, and evaluate it with `eval(s)`, but doing so would be very suspicious. Why exactly would you want this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Looks like XY-problem... Where is the string `s` coming from?

Comment: it prints like that because you have that double quotes, just remove them and s will contain 1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you ask this because you can not use *actual* f-strings, but also don't want to pass the parameters explicitly using `format`, maybe because you do not know which parameter are in the not-really-an-f-string, and also assuming you don't want to use `eval`, because, well, `eval`.

You could pass the variables in the `locals` or `globals` scope to `format`:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> s = '12{x}4'
>>> s.format(**globals())
'1234'
>>> s.format(**locals())
'1234'
```

Depending on where `s` is coming from (user input perhaps?) This might still be a bit risky, though, and it might be better to define a `dict` of "allowed" variables and use that in `format`. As with `globals` and `locals`, any unused variables do not matter.

```
>>> vars = {"x": x, "y": y, "z": z}
>>> s.format(**vars)
```

Note that this does not give you the full power of f-strings, though, which will also *evaluate* expressions. For instance, the above will not work for `s = '12{x*x}4'`.

Comment: This is what I mean yes, Thanks a lot It works!

Answer (score 1):

Remve the double quotations that should fix the issue because the f in a f string needs to be outside the actuall string

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two concepts.

1. The first one, is how you tell python your string is an f-string. The way to do this, is by adding the character 'f' before the first quotation mark:

```py
f"this will be a f-string"
```

2. Whatever you have between {}, it will be a previously defined variable:

```py
x = "something"
f"this will be {x}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd do this -

```
x = 3
s = f'12{x}4'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also work.

```
x = 3 
s = "12{}4"
print(s.format(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove extra commas

```
s = f'12{x}4'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 3 
s = '12{}4'.format(x)
```

or

```
x = 3 
print('12%s4' %x)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question...